# Anova with unequal variances and sample size or multiple t-test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, anova, t-test

I am currently working on cross country average incomes. More specifically, I have figures for the average income in Germany, Spain, Italy and France. I need to test whether average incomes are significantly different from each other (e.g. average income in Italy different from income in Germany etc, average income in Italy different from income in France etc.). I am undecided about how to proceed. I initially thought about doing ANOVA but the sample sizes in the countries of studies are different and so are the variances. At the same time, I don't know if doing multiple t-tests would be the correct procedure.

Comment: Analysis of variance isn't possible without many individual values for income. It's possible geometric means make more sense than means and equivalently that you would be better off looking at variations in log income, Then the unequal variances might be more nearly equal, Unequal sample sizes shouldn't be a problem for any good software. t tests aren't such a good idea.

Comment: *How* different are the variances?  ANOVA handles different sample sizes just fine, but some caution is required when some group sizes are smallish and there are large differences among their variances.

Comment: Thanks both for answering. The sample size in Germany is 2,955 with a variance of 4.189973. Spain has n=1,865 var=4.878995 ; Italy n=1,348 var=3.737909 ; France n=1,721 var=3.777302. Also, I am using Stata 16, if that makes any difference. Would an ANOVA be fine given these sample sizes and variances?

Comment: It could be fine, but incomes have distributions far from normal, so I would be more preoccupoed about that. Can you show us histograms or qqplots?

Comment: ...  or, since this is a oneway anova, you could try an unequal-variance version, and see how different the results are. In R this is `oneway.test` which by default gives the unequal-variance version.

Comment: I checked the income plots and they were all almost normally distributed with the largest kurtosis and skewness in Italy k=3.277 sk= -0.47.